# Merging two file using time

Tags: python-3.x, time

I have a time in following format.

for example

```
time1: 2016-06-07 18:24:19.689
     time 2: 2016-06-07 18:24:21.099
```

If we above times how can we check value of time equal in easy way instead of checking for each value. I am using python. Basically we am trying to merge two log files which are in same time or with in the time limits next to each other.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm guessing you might want to look at `heapq.merge`... not entirely sure though... could you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Convert time into strings and compare them.

```
a = '2016-06-07 18:24:19.689'
b = '2016-06-07 18:24:21.099'
if(a == b):
    # Do your stuff
```